# javascript if/else not working

Tags: javascript

I'am running code in 5th lesson of javascript codecadamy.It is related to prompt and if/else so i'm a java developer, it seems like my code is all correct but it gives the error

```
Oops, try again. Did you add an if statement to your code?
```

instruction to tutorial is as follows:

> Now you have to create different scenarios. Good thing we know how to do that using if / else statements.
>
> If userAnswer is "yes", print out: "You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!"
>
> Otherwise, print out: "Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'"
>
> Remember: `=` is for assignment, and `===` is to check if things are equal!

my code is

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
if (userAnswer === "yes") {
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
} else {
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}
```

Comment: I've voted to close this as the issue isn't reproducible through my browser's JavaScript console. It must be an issue with the tutorial you're following.

Comment: Are you sure you are typing "yes" in the prompt and not "Yes".

Comment: Could you give a direct link?

Comment: is there nothing about the printing method in your tutorial ? try to change console.log with document.write

Comment: note: = is for assignment,  === is to check if things have the same value and the same type, == is to check if two values evaluate to the same thing (a bit tricky sometimes).
example: 0=="0" is true, 0==="0" is false, 0==false is true, "1E+2"==100 is true; "1E+2"===100 is false, ...

Comment: @meskobalazs http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-x9DnD/0/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Answer (score 0):

Works with toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() methods:

```
if (userAnswer.toLowerCase()=='yes') { 
   console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
} else { 
   console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that print the first message even if my answer is "no"?

Comment: prompt box is used so if(userAnswer) will check for Ok.

Comment: the toLowerCase has nothing to do here, read the tutorial instructions. 'If userAnswer is "yes"'.

Comment: no, only if it is yes then first message should get print other than yes it should print second message

Comment: I guess what Codeacademy wants here is the answer should be "Yes" and not "yes"

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-x9DnD/0/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: Yes, even if you type in lowercase "yes", you need to use toLowerCase() method, I don't know why, there might be something bug in js...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few things, something is definitely wrong with the tutorial (as the code works perfectly otherwise), others are complaining in the Q&A section too, there is no posted solution for this. It was working a year ago, but it was with a bit different text.

So for the time being, you should just skip this part of the tutorial, and report it as not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the answer which is working 100% i got it  [https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5303b63e52f8632b29004fe5][1]

  // Check if the user is ready to play!
   confirm("I am ready");
age = prompt("What is your age?");
if (age < 13)
{
console.log("You are too young to play, but I take no responsibility");
} 
else 
{
console.log("Play on!"); }
console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
if (userAnswer === "yes") 
{
console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}
else
{
console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'"); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the answer:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
if(userAnswer === "yes") 
{ 
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}
else
{
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing."); 
}
```